# Firebase Pricing Miscalculation / Discrepancy

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I think there is some miscalculation in the [Firebase pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) with regards to the cost of GB Transferred in the Blaze plan. The quoted $0.12/GB seems quite high. In comparison the Flame plan comes with 50GB/day. At the Blaze plan rate of $0.12/GB, 50GB/day would cost around $180 just for the GB Transferred. However, the Flame plan only costs $25 and includes a lot of other stuff. I think there's some miscalculation in the pricing displayed on the site.

By comparison GB Transferred for hosting the Blaze plan costs $0.15/GB and the Flame plan includes 50GB/month. So it's like 6X cheaper in Blaze than Flame. But for Storage its the other way around? I think there's a mixup here with the daily and monthly.

Anyone know if this is the case from experience? Perhaps there's also a way to calculate this from Google Cloud pricing to see if it's accurate? Would be great to get some clarification on this before I run up a tab.

Comment: If you have questions about billing for Firebase, please contact Firebase support directly.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: Thanks just sent them this question :). All the pricing seems really fair on their calculator except for this so I'm wondering why it's this way

Answer (score 0):

**In the case of GB stored.**

```
In Flame - 50GB for $25/month
In Blaze for 50GB : 50*$0.026 = $1.3
```

**In the case of GB downloaded.**

```
In Flame - 50GB/day for 30 days month : 50*30 = 1500GB
In Blaze for 50GB/day for 30 days month : 50*30*$0.12 = $180 Way cheaper 
considering the fact that the limit will be reached at just 50GB/day.
This is very important for apps at scale where 50GB limit can be reached in no
time an peak traffic sessions
```

**For Hosting data transferred:**

```
In Flame - 50GB/Month for $25
In Blaze for 50GB : 50*$0.15 = $7.5
```

> **The rate given in Firebase Blaze is applicable at the end of the month depending upon the actual usage.**
>
> It can be cheaper. The Flame plan is for developers who want
>   assurances that the bill can never go over a certain amount. But with
>   the Blaze plan, you only pay for what is consumed, which could be a
>   small amount if you are not consuming much.

Comment: Yes I get this but how come the price / GB is so much cheaper in Flame...?

Comment: The GB Transferred not stored. GB Transferred is $0.12/GB

Comment: Even then 50*30*$0.12 = $180 Way cheaper considering the fact that the limit will be reached at just 50GB/day

Comment: how is $180 cheaper than $25?

Comment: when app is at scale, 50GB limit will be reached in no time and applications will become buggy and unresponsive